# Dealing with too many terminal nodes in grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to write a parser for protobuf3 using the grammars from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/protobuf3/Protobuf3.g4.

and I'm trying to deal with the _type declaration in my grammar:

```
field
  : ( REPEATED )? type_ fieldName EQ fieldNumber ( LB fieldOptions RB )? SEMI
  ;

type_
  : DOUBLE
  | FLOAT
  | INT32
  | INT64
  | UINT32
  | UINT64
  | SINT32
  | SINT64
  | FIXED32
  | FIXED64
  | SFIXED32
  | SFIXED64
  | BOOL
  | STRING
  | BYTES
  | messageDefinition
  | enumType
  ;
```

Inside `enterField` I have this snippet:

```java
    @Override
    public void enterField(Protobuf3Parser.FieldContext ctx) {
        MessageDefinition messageDefinition = this.messageStack.peek();
        Field field = new Field();
        field.setName(ctx.fieldName().ident().getText());
        field.setPosition(ctx.fieldNumber().getAltNumber());
        messageDefinition.addField(field);
        super.enterField(ctx);
    }
```

However I'm not sure on how I can deal with the `type_` context here. It has too many terminal nodes (for basic types) and it could have a messageType or an enumType.

For my use case all I care about is if it is a basic type (and in that case get the type name) or if it is a complex type (such as another message or enum) get the definition name.

Is there a way to do this without having to check each possible outcome of `ctx.field_()` ?

Thank you

Comment: You could just get the name of the type (ctx.type_().getText()) and stuff that into your Field class.

Comment: That works, in the end I just need to switch between the base types, message and enum. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both, `messageDefinition` and `enumType` return single lexer token, you can make the entire access very easy by using a label:

```
type_
  : value = DOUBLE
  | value = FLOAT
  | value = INT32
  | value = INT64
  | value = UINT32
  | value = UINT64
  | value = SINT32
  | value = SINT64
  | value = FIXED32
  | value = FIXED64
  | value = SFIXED32
  | value = SFIXED64
  | value = BOOL
  | value = STRING
  | value = BYTES
  | value = messageDefinition
  | value = enumType
  ;
```

With that you only need to use the field `value`:

```
    @Override
    public void enterField(Protobuf3Parser.FieldContext ctx) {
        ...

        const type = ctx.type_().value.getText();
        ...

        super.enterField(ctx);
    }
```